# overllaping Datatables columns on fixed columns while horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I have created table using datatables. I want to fixed first 2 columns.

But other two columns are overllaping on it while scrolling horizontally.

If I take the fixed column out, the table Scrolls correctly without overllaping and If I add the fixed column, the tables columns overlaps on fixed columns while scrolling horizontally

Here you can see how Capacity column is overllaping on Equipment Name: [image]

Html Code:

```
<style>
  .bg-dark {
    background-color: #2980b9 !important;
  }

  .thead-dark th {
    background-color: #2980b9 !important;
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  }

  .table td,
  .table th {
    height: 1em;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    padding: 5px 5px;
  }

  .table-scroll {
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }

</style>




 <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table dataTable table-striped table-bordered" id="equipmentCostData">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <tr>
                        <th>OPCO</th>
                        <th>Equipment Name</th>
                        <th>Capacity</th>
                        <th>Annual<br/> Distance</th>
                        <th>Equipment <br/> Price</th>
                        <th>Tyre Type</th>
                        <th>Tyre <br/> Count</th>
                        <th>Finance<br/> Fleet %</th>
                        <th>Target <br/> Profit %</th>
                        <th>Loan <br/> Amount %</th>
                        <th>Interest <br/> Rate %</th>
                        <th>Loan<br/> Years</th>
                        <th>Amortization <br/> Years</th>
                        <th>Residual<br/> Value</th>
                        <th>Maintenance Cost/Unit <br/> Distance</th>
                        <th> Tax </th>
                        <th>Insurance</th>
                        <th>Admin <br/> Cost</th>
                        <th>Other Cost <br/> (Misc.)</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {% for e in equipment %}
                      <tr id="{{e.id}}">
                        <td>{{e.opco_id__opco_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.equipment_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.capacity}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.annual_distance}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.cost}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.tyre_type_id__tyre_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.tyre_count}}</td>
                        <td{{e.finance_fleet}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.target_profit}}</td> 
                        <td>{{e.loan_amount}}</td> 
                        <td>{{e.interest_rate}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.loan_years}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.amotization_years}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.residual_value}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.maintenance_cost_per_unit_distance}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.tax}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.insurance}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.admin_cost}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.other_cost}}</td>
                        <td> 
                          <i class='fa fa-edit editBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                          <i class='fa fa-trash pl-3 deleteBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                        </td>
                        
                      </tr>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="{% static 'js/jquery.datatables.min.js' %}"
></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/4.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>   
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $("#equipmentCostData").DataTable({ 
                  fixedColumns: true,
                  fixedColumns: {
                    left: 2,
                    right: 0
                  },
                  
                  responsive: true,
                });
            });
</script>
```

How Can I Fixed 2 Columns without overllapping it.

Comment: It's more of a hack than a fix, but I resolved this by adding a solid clour background to the fixed column cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

I have set style `background colour` and `z-index` to the fixed columns. Means First 2 columns.

```
<div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table dataTable table-striped table-bordered" id="equipmentCostData">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th style="z-index: 2 !important;">OPCO</th>
                    <th style="z-index: 2 !important;">Equipment Name</th>
                    <th>Capacity</th>
                    <th>Annual<br/> Distance</th>
                    <th>Equipment <br/> Price</th>
                    <th>Tyre Type</th>
                    <th>Tyre <br/> Count</th>
                    <th>Finance<br/> Fleet %</th>
                    <th>Target <br/> Profit %</th>
                    <th>Loan <br/> Amount %</th>
                    <th>Interest <br/> Rate %</th>
                    <th>Loan<br/> Years</th>
                    <th>Amortization <br/> Years</th>
                    <th>Residual<br/> Value</th>
                    <th>Maintenance Cost/Unit <br/> Distance</th>
                    <th> Tax </th>
                    <th>Insurance</th>
                    <th>Admin <br/> Cost</th>
                    <th>Other Cost <br/> (Misc.)</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for e in equipment %}
                  <tr id="{{e.id}}">
                    <td style="background-color: white !important;">{{e.opco_id__opco_name}}</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white !important;">{{e.equipment_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.capacity}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.annual_distance}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.cost}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.tyre_type_id__tyre_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.tyre_count}}</td>
                    <td{{e.finance_fleet}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.target_profit}}</td> 
                    <td>{{e.loan_amount}}</td> 
                    <td>{{e.interest_rate}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.loan_years}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.amotization_years}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.residual_value}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.maintenance_cost_per_unit_distance}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.tax}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.insurance}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.admin_cost}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.other_cost}}</td>
                    <td> 
                      <i class='fa fa-edit editBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                      <i class='fa fa-trash pl-3 deleteBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                    </td>
                    
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
```